# Xcode 6 Beta 2 - iOS Simulator error and elements rearranged

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, swift, ios8, xcode6

I am new to Xcode 6 and Swift, so I was checking it out and crafting a simple app but I encountered several problems:

1. When I run my app the keyboard does not react to whenever I "press" (click since I am in the simulator) in the text field. That is, the keyboard does not show up.
2. The app's elements in the storyboard TOTALLY rearrange sometimes when I mess around with the width and height of the storyboard and choose an different device for the iOS simulator.

All my problems and (little) code I've written is as shown:

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

I would appreciate any tips/help you guys can give me!

Thank you in advance!

Jack.

Comment: Those are completely unrelated issues. Stack Overflow works best when you ask one question per question. That way you can get into the specifics of each, rather than a broad catch-all "I'm having a bunch of problems" like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I have had similar issue some times on simulator, use **⌘+K** or **Hardware > Keyboard > Toggle Software Keyboard** to prompt keyboard.
2. When change width and height of storyboard, examine closely the the descriptions (width, height, portrait, landscape) in the popup, I suggest choose the width and height that matches your device and orientation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! the first one I figured it out but thank you for responding! The second one is still causing some problems though

Comment: I suggest try create a clean new project and redo UI, see where goes wrong, experiment with different sizes and find pattern of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of auto layout. Here is a link to guide you through. 
[Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)